# How to get touch event or click listener of View during animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an imageview which i am moving from position A to position B, during that animation if user click or touch the moving imageview, animation should stop or cleared.

Comment: Pl share your code what you have tried

Comment: What kind of animation are you using? TranslateAnimation or ObjectAnimator or what?

Comment: I am playing TranslateAnimation

Answer (score 0):

You should use 
[View.clearAnimation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#clearAnimation())